# Get recommended video with API 3.0

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I've read the Youtube API documentation and I've read that the GData 2.0 API had the [recommended videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_recommendations):

I've to use the API 3.0, but I wasn't able to find anything about recommended: does anyone know a way to retrieve them?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?access_token=[your token]&part=[your parts]&home=true
```

the response is the recommended videos.

Comment: This is what I had the most success with. For each result, there is a "type" field, and many of the results are "recommendation".

Comment: The ```home``` paramter is now deprecated, is there any other API that I can use?

Comment: the above url always returns empty list.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an exact type of feed in Data API v3 yet. You can mimic at least the most viewed ones using [search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but recommended and most viewed aren't the same. I've understand, reading a lot of article, that api 3.0 are now a "work in progress" and some 2.0 api will be released in the near future. Infact 2.0 API aren't deprecates.

Comment: We strongly suggest to use Data API v3, there are few features that will be coming from v2 really soon.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ibrahim, I'll wait for them

Comment: I've encountered this `search`  ,  what does it do exactly? Will it automatically browse the playlist and randomly pick a video?